# Kafka consumer latency

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, latency

I faced considerable latency in receiving topic messages and thought of writing this test program which uses spring kafka and apache kafka. I am using a test program to send data to a topic and use the following consumers to log latency of receiving the message in consumer. Difference between record timestamp and time actually received in consumer.

**Spring Consumer**

```java
@Component
public class SpringKafkaConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "websocket",
        containerFactory = "dynamicKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveDeliveryTopic(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, @Headers   MessageHeaders headers) {
    Log.info("0", "Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: {} latency: {}", record.topic(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() - record.timestamp());
}
```

**Apache Consumer**

```java
@Component
public class ApacheKafkaConsumer {
    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "test");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("websocket"));

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                Log.info("0", "Latency in apache kafka consumer: {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - record.timestamp());
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

**Spring Consumer**

```
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 246
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 246
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 247
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 267
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 260
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 261
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 260
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 306
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 300
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 300
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 299
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 340
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 337
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 337
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 337
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 345
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 345
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 345
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 346
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 356
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 352
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 350
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 349
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 359
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 355
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 354
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 354
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 361
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 360
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 360
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 360
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 354
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 351
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 351
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 350
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 358
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 356
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 356
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 356
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 362
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 362
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 356
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 356
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 363
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 361
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 359
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 359
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 358
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 351
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 352
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 351
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 370
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 370
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 369
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 368
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 368
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 366
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 366
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 364
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 366
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 365
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 360
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 360
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 360
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 360
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 358
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 358
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 358
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 359
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 356
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 353
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 370
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 363
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 362
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 361
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 379
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 378
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 379
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 373
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 371
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 371
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 366
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 372
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 366
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 366
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 366
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 364
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 374
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 368
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 367
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 366
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 367
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 362
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 363
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 362
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 362
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 361
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 364
Kafka latency in spring receiver: Topic: websocket latency: 363
```

**Apache Consumer**

```
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 134  
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 130
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 130
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 130
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 130
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 138
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 133
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 133
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 131
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 143
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 141
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 141
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 142
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 140
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 143
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 137
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 225
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 224
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 225
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 223
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 225
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 222
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 217
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 217
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 217
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 230
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 234
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 233
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 233
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 233
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 231
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 231
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 230
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 228
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 226
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 225
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 229
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 226
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 226
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 227
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 227
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 258
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 253
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 252
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 252
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 254
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 252
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 263
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 262
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 261
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 261
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 261
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 257
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 256
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 255
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 270
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 269
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 266
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 263
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 263
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 263
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 262
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 263
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 260
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 257
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 254
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 253
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 253
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 271
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 270
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 267
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 270
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 266
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 266
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 266
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 266
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 264
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 296
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 295
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 297
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 293
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 294
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 298
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 297
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 295
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 295
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 298
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 298
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 302
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 302
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 302
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 300
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 303
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 302
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 303
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 301
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 300
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 299
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 300
Latency in apache kafka consumer: 299
```

Why am I seeing this high latency in kafka consumer?

Comment: What kind of latency would you expect? How many computers is this running on and what is the ping between producers, Kafka brokers and consumers? What's the CPU/network/disk load on the broker? What's the difference between `System.currentTimeMillis()` among the producer and the consumer? Do not assume their clock are in perfect sync.

Comment: producer, consumer and Kafka is running on localhost. How can I measure latency if this is not accurate. I would not expect more than 2-3ms for transport latency in Kafka based on their claims

Comment: Interesting! I assume you explicitly set your batch.size and linger.ms to 0? If not, try that, producers can batch messages up. If that doesn't help, try manually flushing the producer after every message to see where the latency is coming from.

Comment: I called `flush` after each send and now see better results in consumer. Does that mean asynchronous send cannot be fast in kafka?

Comment: Tried with batch-size and linger-ms to 0 and saw no improvement